# Laravel RESTfull Api: Method PUT Not Allowed

Tags: php, laravel, rest

How do I set up a vue + php bundle to update a record?

here I send data to php in json format, the data is all present - checked:

```
// Update
          fetch('api/article', {
              method: 'put',
              body: JSON.stringify(this.article),
              headers: {
                  'content-type': 'application/json'
              }
          })
```

next my routes in
**api.php**

```
//Create New Article
Route::post('article','ArticleController@store');

//Update Article
Route::patch('article','ArticleController@store');

//Delete Article
Route::delete('article/{id}','ArticleController@destroy');
```

and my controller
**ArticleController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $article = $request->isMethod('patch') ? Article::findOrFail
        ($request->article_id) : new Article;

        $article->id = $request->input('id');
        $article->title = $request->input('title');
        $article->body = $request->input('body');

        if ($article->save()) {
            return new ArticleResource($article);
        }
    }
```

in the console with this configuration, I get:

```
PUT https://example.com/api/article 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Tell me how to configure it correctly

Comment: You have no `put` route declared in your `routes.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change it to patch

```
          fetch('api/article', {
              method: 'patch',
              body: JSON.stringify(this.article),
              headers: {
                  'content-type': 'application/json'
              }
          })
```

Comment: in console: `patch 404 (Not Found)`